# ContentObserver stops working after some time

Tags: android, android-4.4-kitkat, android-appwidget, contentobserver

I'm writing simple widget with ListView. I wanted to get instant updates on data changes so created ContentObserver. I'm registering it in RemoteViewFactory descendant class.

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://mms-sms/conversations");
    final String[] projection = new String[]{"*"};
    _dataCursor = _context.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null, null, "date DESC");

    if(_smsObserver == null) {
        _smsObserver = new SmsObserver(new Handler(), _context);
    }

    _context.getContentResolver().registerContentObserver(uri, true, _smsObserver);
}
```

ContentObserver is unregistered in same class:

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    if(_dataCursor != null && !_dataCursor.isClosed())
    {
        _dataCursor.close();
    }

    if(_smsObserver != null) {
        _context.getContentResolver().unregisterContentObserver(_smsObserver);
    }
}
```

It works just fine for some time, mayby few hours, but after night, ContentObserver stops working and my App Widget is not getting updated. There is no advanced code in `OnChange` method.

```
@Override
public void onChange(boolean selfChange) {
    super.onChange(selfChange);
    Intent smsIntent = new Intent(_context, SmsWidget.class);
    smsIntent.setAction(SmsWidget.RELOAD_ACTION);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(_context, 0, smsIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    try {
        pendingIntent.send();
    } catch (PendingIntent.CanceledException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I'm testing my App Widget on device with Android 4.4.2.

I tried to move registration and unregistration of ContentObserver from `RemoteViewsFactory` to `AppWidgetProvider` itself to `OnEnabled()` and `OnDisabled()` methods. Unfortunatelly it did not work as it should. After around 8h ContentObserver must have been unregistered as my AppWidget stopped getting update intents.

Answer (score 1):

I've faced similar problem. My workaround solution is to broadcast a customized intent action to AppWidgetProvider since it's a receiver.